# How can I play a keyframe animation on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, css-animations, keyframe

I want to create a keyframe Animation each time when I click at the box. But when I click onto the box the animation just works one time. I want that the animation works everytime when I click onto the box.

Any help?
Thanks!

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#rocketstart").click(function(){
            $(".rocket").css("animation-play-state", "running");
        });

    });
```

```css
.rocket {
   background-color: red;
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: -340px;
    margin-bottom: -110px;
    animation-name: rocket;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rocket {
   0%   {  transform:translate(0)    }
   100%  {  transform:translate(0, -50%) }
       70%  {  opacity:1; }
       100%  {  opacity:0; }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rocket' id="rocketstart" title="rocketup">
```

Comment: Your answer is detailed clearly here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Tips

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of changing the state of animation, move the animation property into a new class and remove that class at the end of animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#rocketstart").click(function(){
            $(".rocket").addClass("animated");
        });


        $('.rocket').on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd", function(){
             $(this).removeClass("animated");
        });
    });
```

```css
.rocket {
   background-color: red;
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-right: -340px;
    margin-bottom: -110px;

}

.animated{
    animation-name: rocket;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes rocket {
   0%   {  transform:translate(0)    }
   100%  {  transform:translate(0, -50%) }
       70%  {  opacity:1; }
       100%  {  opacity:0; }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='rocket' id="rocketstart" title="rocketup">
```

Comment: Alternatively, instead of toggling whole animation on `animationend` you can use `animationiteration` event and toggle `animation-play-state`. This requires the animation to have `animation-iteration-count: infinite`